# Custom callout (mapBox iOS sdk)

Tags: ios, objective-c, mapbox

i want to create callout with custom view - such as this one [image]
<sub>(source: [arcgis.com](https://developers.arcgis.com/ios/guide/GUID-D0A3C19D-9802-4973-96EE-CA2BC071C885-web.png))</sub>

But i can't find any workaround to do this stuff, only solution i find is to use following code:

```
- (RMMapLayer *)mapView:(RMMapView *)mapView layerForAnnotation:(RMAnnotation *)annotation

         ... 
        marker = [[RMMarker alloc] initWithUIImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"marker.png"]]; 
        UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil]; 
        CalloutViewController* callout = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"callout"]; 
        [marker setLabel:callout.view];
}
```

but result not quite what i want, because when I set the label property of the marker, the view appears without tapping on the marker.

Any idea how to solve this problem? Or maybe there's some other approaches to achieve this?

EDIT:

also i find this article on [github](https://github.com/mapbox/DEPRECATED-mapbox-ios-sdk/pull/314), but i can't figure out how to implement it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

look at https://github.com/iNima/mapbox-ios-sdk/blob/91d8614fa4549b25dd8b647d82f270382c279a8c/MapView/Map/RMMapView.m

it tells you that on click the RMMapView class will handle showing a callout for you given your marker's layer has `canShowCallout == YES` and `title != nil` set on it

if your marker fulfils this you get the same callout as with MapKit :)

set contentView or left- or right- CalloutView variables to modify that callout view

```
- (RMMapLayer *)mapView:(RMMapView *)mapView layerForAnnotation:(RMAnnotation *)annotation

     ... 
    marker = [[RMMarker alloc] initWithUIImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"marker.png"]]; 
    [marker setCanShowCallout:YES];
    [marker setTitle"Test"];

    //Following only works with iNimas version
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil]; 
    CalloutViewController* callout = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"callout"]; 
    [marker setContentView:callout.view];

    return marker ; 
}
```

Comment: NOTE: the contentView is only available in iNima's version of the sdk!

Comment: the original SDK only support title, leftCalloutAccessoryView and rightCalloutAccessoryView

Answer (score 1):

This is outside the scope of the SDK, as it's done in the `SMCalloutView` dependent project. Since both are open source, you can add this behavior but it's currently not possible.

(I wrote the SDK in question).

Comment: SMCallout already has a contentView property that works fine. There is even a PR outstanding to add this https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-ios-sdk/pull/449